# Specific Verbs for Eyes

Tags: translation, verb

Good day everyone!

I wanted to find verbs related to the eyes but, I couldn't find some of the specific English verbs in German. **To see** is **sehen**, **look** is **aussehen** and **to watch** is **ansehen**. However, I couldn't find **glare**, **gaze** and **glance** in the dictionary. Are there any German word exist for those English words? If there are any words that related to the eyes that you know (especially when it has no specific English translation), feel free to post it in the answer too, thank you.

[EDIT]

1. DWDS is too difficult for beginners like me to use.
2. In dict.leo.org, the translation of **glare** is not what I was
   expecting, all of the translation relates to the sun or other
   sparkly objects. What I want is a German verb of "**to look angrily** at
   something/someone".
3. As @mic said, there's not necessarily one German verb for one
   English verb - and vice versa. Which is why I asked for specific
   verbs that relates to the eyes, because some words may not exist in
   German and there may be German words that does not exist in English.
   I simply want to know words that exist in both languages and those
   that not exist in another. As in *Bahasa Indonesia*, it has a specific
   word for "to shake hand with someone", which is **berjabat** but, in
   English we need two words; **shake hands**, which means there is no specific word for berjabat.

Comment: Looking into a decent dictionary here should be sufficient, e.g. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gucken) if you scroll down to *Thesaurus* with the synonyms....

Comment: or https://dict.leo.org

Comment: You could also try [pons.com](https://pons.com/de/dict/search/deen/glare)

Comment: Isn't *berjabat* just a shortcut for *berjabat tangan* ("shake hands")?

Comment: *to look angrily at someone* is either *anblitzen* (short and fierce) or *niederstarren* (long and painful).

Comment: @Janka, you can use _berjabatan_ without _tangan_ though

Comment: Regarding the concept of "one word" vs. "several words": word boundaries are are relatively volatile thing in many languages. You juxtapose *berjabat* with *shake hands*, but in German it can be *händeschütteln* as well as *Hände schütteln*. I think it is best to just skip the concept of "one word" vs. "several words" and look for expressions of how many "words" ever. More important is the semantic content or concept behind the (cluster of) words.

Comment: @Logos: we are at implicit meanings then. For example one meaning of *einschlagen* is *to make a contract by shakehands*.

Comment: dict.leo,org **does** have the translation of *glare* you are looking for. You just need to scroll down

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvote? I am not asking direct and simple translation here, it's about word preferences and language differences.

Comment: @Janka, I should've used _titip_ in the example above but, since that word is untranslatable to both English and German, it's very hard to use it as explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As this will become a collection, I am starting a community wiki. - For English equivalents you may then refer to a good dictionary.

- beäugen
- betrachten
- blicken, anblicken
- blinzeln, anblinzeln
- blitzen, anblitzen
- fixieren
- fokussieren
- gaffen, begaffen
- glotzen, anglotzen
- die Augen über etwas gleiten lassen
- glupschen, anglupschen, beglupschen
- gucken (kucken), ankucken
- linsen, in etwas hineinlinsen
- schauen, anschauen
- den Blick schweifen lassen über etwas
- sehen, ansehen, besehen
- spähen
- starren, anstarren, niederstarren
- Stielaugen machen
- stieren, anstieren
- die Augen über etwas streifen lassen
- zwinkern, anzwinkern

There are other idioms (usually compounds) that are quite related, but usually they are not used to the act of "looking" as such, rather to the looking being part of a wider scenery:

- dumm aus der Wäsche kucken
- in die Röhre kucken
- bedröppelt kucken
- mit Rehaugen kucken
- mit Dackelaugen kucken
- Krokodilstränen vergießen

Other words are used for activities that necessarily include looking (i.e. using the eyes) but rather describe a broader type of behaviour

- spechten
- jemanden ausspähen (other activity than simply *spähen*)

Comment: Would you mind to include the meanings please? Thank you :)

Comment: @Logos  What about you looking them up in a dictionary and entering the English translations or equivalents here? This answer is a community wiki and you should be able to edit it (hopefully, not sure about possible credit point requirements for this though)

Comment: Oh, I can edit it? Thanks, I'll try to do it after work :)

Answer (score 1):

It's true and obvious that there's not necessarily one German verb for one English verb - and vice versa.

If you want to translate "glare" as "to look angrily at s.o." you may have to add a German adjective to describe this anger.
But actually [dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/glare) gives you all you need in this specific case:

**anblitzen**
"anfunkeln" is an alternative.

And if you go to [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/) with these words, you get some good examples:

> Diederich blitzte ihn so furchtbar an, daß er zurückschrak
>
> Sie ... funkelte mich mit ihren großen Augen zornig an

Comment: Yes, you are correct that there's not necessarily one German verb for one English verb - and vice versa. Which is why I asked for **specific verbs** that relates to the eyes, because some words may not exist in German and there may be German words that does not exist in English. I simply want to know words that exist in both languages and those that not exist in another. As in _Bahasa Indonesia_, it has a specific word for "to shake hand with someone", which is **berjabat** but, in English we need two words; **shake hands**.